# Emulating String concat behaviour from VB6 in C

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to port a program from VB6 to plain C. A lot of functions use multiple instances of the `&` Operator to concatenate Strings like this:

(VB6 Code)

```
Public Function myFunc (myString As String) As String
Dim myNewString As String
myNewString = globalString & myString
myFunc = myNewString
End Function
```

The intent behind that is to concatenate different strings together. This is done exhaustively on multiple hundred occasions in the code.

I currently emulate this behavior like this:

```
sprintf(myString, "%s%s", myString, newString);
```

the strings are declared like this:

```
char myString[500] = {};
char newString[100] = {};
```

Its very important to note that never will my concatenate operations exceed the max length of the string, as that is not possible with any scenarios this program deals with.

My question is now:

- Assuming that I never exceed the max length of the `char` arrays, is this a safe and performing way to emulate this operation (I have not run into any issue so far with it in production testing)
- Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: why did not you use [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *1. [...] is this a safe and performing way to emulate this operation (I have not run into any issue so far with it in production testing)*

No, not at all. Your code,

```
sprintf(myString, "%s%s", myString, newString);
```

produces [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As mentioned in the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.6, The `sprintf()` function

> [...] If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Then,

> *2. Are there better ways to do this?*

Yes, sure. You should be using [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) to concatenate the strings.

Comment: Mhm, I guess I'll have to change that then. I can't really have UB in my code if its going to run production, even if it works currently...

Answer (score 1):

If the destination string is large enough and already contains a valid, null-terminated string, simply use `strcat`.

```
strcat(myString, newString);
```

Comment: Does this have a substantially improved effect or is it generally speaking exactly the same as what im doing right now?

Comment: Maybe it's worthy to mention that the current code is UB. :)

Comment: @Magisch It is roughly some hundred times more efficient than the printf family of functions, in terms of speed and memory consumption.